# Need to repeat a function a certain number of times, and return a new variable name each time

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on this as part of a larger application. Basically, I'll be asking the user how many servers there are in total, then requesting the name of each, and grabbing the servers IP. Based on the users input of the total number of servers, I'd like to be able to repeat the process that many times.

Thinking something like this will work, but I'm pretty sure the section about unpacking the tuples to variables won't.

```
def add_servers():
    Server_name = raw_input("Please enter the server name for the next server: ")
    server_IP = socket.gethostbyname(Server_name)
    return (Server_name,server_IP)

def primary_server():
    PServerName = raw_input("Please enter the name for the primary server: ")
    PS_IP = socket.gethostbyname(PServerName)
    return (PServerName,PS_IP)

#Grab the total number of servers.
total_servers = int(raw_input("Please enter the total number of servers: "))
if total_servers > 1:
    add_servs = int(total_servers - 1)
    primary_server()
    for server in range(add_servs):
        add_servers()
        Server_name, server_IP = add_servers()
else:
    primary_server() #If there is only 1 server, don't subtract, and run the function for the primary server only.
    PServer, PS_IP = primary_server()
```

Comment: Stick them in a dictionary instead, have each server_name correspond with the server_ip as the key.

Comment: You need not worry about whether unpacking the tuple will work. What you are doing with `Server_name, server_IP = add_servers()` works

Answer (score 2):

Why not try something like this using dictionaries?:

```
secondary_servers = {}
total_servers = int(raw_input("Please enter the total number of servers: "))
if total_servers > 1:
    add_servs = int(total_servers - 1)
    primary_server()
    for server in range(add_servs):
        Server_name, server_IP = add_servers()
        if Server_name not in secondary_servers.keys():
            secondary_servers[Server_name] = server_IP
```

That way all your secondary servers are in a dictionary. You can change it to an OrderedDict() if you need to maintain order. Otherwise just use a list and keep appending the tuples to the list.

Per the comments, this is the revised suggestion factoring in the other answer:

```
server_count = None

while server_count is None:
    total_servers = input('Please enter total number of servers: ')
    try:
        server_count = int(total_servers)
    except ValueError:
        total_servers = input('That is not a valid number, try again: ')

servers = {}  # This is an empty dict
for i in range(1, server_count+1):
    if i == 1:
        servers["Primary Server"] = primary_server()
    else:
        servers["Secondary Server " + str(i)] = add_servers()
```

Comment: Wouldn't I have to call `add_servers()` at some point though?

Comment: It's called here. Server_name, server_IP = add_servers(). Although I would go with the other answer in combination with using dictionaries. As it is a more cleaner approach to your logic loop.

Comment: I'm testing it now, but would there be a way to label the entries, instead of assigning the server name as the key? I'll be using the dictionary later in the larger application, and can't rely on the server names as keys, as they will be different each time the script is run.

Comment: Possibly use the IP address then as the keys. They keys are just there to pair each of the items. That way you know which hostname will correspond with which ip address.

Comment: Right, but both the server AND IP will be different each time. (this is meant to be run for different clients) Would it be possible to somehow assign a key like `secondary_servers['Server1Name'] = Server_name` and `secondary_servers['Server1IP'] = server_IP`?

Comment: See the bottom edit for an example of how that would be done. The end result would give you a dictionary where each key would be the server and the value would be a tuple of (name, ip).

Answer (score 0):

Use a list to collect the servers, and loop until the length of the list is the same as your input number:

```
server_count = None

while server_count is None:
    total_servers = input('Please enter total number of servers: ')
    try:
        server_count = int(total_servers)
    except ValueError:
        total_servers = input('That is not a valid number, try again: ')

servers = []  # This is an empty list
while len(servers) != server_count:
    if len(servers) < 1:
        servers.append(primary_server())
    else:
        servers.append(add_servers())
```